# I want to fill NA of this rate column (character class)

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have the data like this:

```
  rate
1  30%
2  50%
3  NA
4  2.65%
5. NA
```

And I want to fill NA of this rate column to be the mean of values this total column. Since the rate column is character class. I do not know how to do this:
I want the result like this: (30%+50%+2.65%)/3=27.55%

```
  rate 
1  30%
2  50%
3  27.55%
4  2.65%
5. 27.55%
```

Since the rate column is character class. I do not know how to do this. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer to you this solution, but maybe some pro users of `R-tag` will advice more elegant answer.

**Your data:**

```
df <- data.frame(rate = c("30%", "50%", NA, "2.65%", NA))
```

**Remove our `%` before calculating `mean`**

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- mutate_all(df, function(x) as.numeric(sub("%","",x)))
```

**Replacing NAs to our average value:**

```
df1[is.na(df1)] <- colMeans(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**And result:**

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~paste0(., "%")))

    rate
1    30%
2    50%
3 27.55%
4  2.65%
5 27.55%
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But when I run this code:"Data2[is.na(Data2)] <- colMeans(Data2, na.rm = TRUE) in my data frame, it has the error:Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(analysisData2), value = c(1, : 'value' is the wrong length

Comment: I am not sure how to solve it, Thank you so much!!

Comment: @GuiW Can you add a code chunk with your data(or a part)? I'm a newbie also, i should see and try ;)